# How to crop image shape wise?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am developing photo editor app. I have given photo crop in rectangle shape. I inspired from picsart they crop photo in various shapes like heart, triangle etc.. 
I need help with above situation. Any help will be appreciated. 
Preferred language swift Or objective c

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these image editing libraries

Swift

- https://github.com/ZaidPathan/ZImageCropper
- https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController

Objective-C

- https://github.com/jberlana/JBCroppableView
- https://github.com/nitingohel/NGCropview